# Is it possible to parse the templateURL in an Angular component?

Tags: html, angular, parsing, templates

I wish to generate a Table of Contents ( ToC ) by parsing the HTML that is already present in the `templateUrl` of my component.

This is my component.ts :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-presentation',
  templateUrl: './presentation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./presentation.component.css']
})
export class PresentationComponent implements OnInit {
  public toc = '';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // parse tempalteUrl here
    // set the this.toc variable
  }
}
```

and this is my component.html :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      {{toc}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h2>Sub Title1</h2>
      <p>some text</p>
      <h2>Sub Title2</h2>
      <p>more text</p>
      <h1>Title2</h1>
      <h2>Sub Title3</h2>
      <p>random text</p>
      <h2>Sub Title4</h2>
      <p>extra text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I wish to do is to extract all of the  and children  and then use them to generate the ToC.

Only `<div class="col-sm-8">` has the elements I am interested in
All `<h1>` are direct children of that div
All `<h2>` are direct children of a `<h1>`

The aim of what I am trying to do is have as little HTML as possible to edit at each update when I want to change the content of my website.

Comment: you can inject ElementRef in constructor then get the html by calling this.elRef.nativeElement.innerHTML. this is safe enough for reading, however if you want to manipulate it Angular recommends using Renderer2

Comment: I am possibly not using it correctly : tried to do : 
`constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML);
}`
but I end up with an empty string. I can see the content when logging nativeElement directly but else no. What am I not doing correctly ?

Comment: you need to do it in ngOnInit or later cause if you do it in the constructor the view hasn't been initialized yet that's why empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple ways I can think of are inject ElementRef if just reading whole HTML doc, Renderer2 if going to modify HTML and output in ngOnInit(); add template ref and read ViewChild in ngAfterViewInit()

`<div #toc class="col-sm-8">...</div>`

```
import { Component , ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('toc') toc: ElementRef;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.elRef.nativeElement.innerHTML);
  }

  //template ref + viewChild
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.toc.nativeElement.innerHTML);
  }
}
```